# Does the tensor product distribute over a direct sum exactly if all the involved modules are bimodules?

Tags: tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra, direct-sum

Given a non-commutative ring $R$, a right module $M$, and a left module $N$, we can define the tensor product $M \otimes_R N$. I suspect that
$$
\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i\right) \otimes_R N \simeq \bigoplus_{i=1}^n (M_i \otimes_R N) \tag{1} \label{eq:1}
$$
if and only if $M_1,\dotsc,M_n,N$ are all *bimodules*, possibly with the added hypothesis that $R$ is unital, but so far I have been able to prove it. Is this actually true? If not, are there other results on the distributivity of the tensor product for non-commutative rings?

**Note:** This problem is motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593274/problem-with-the-ring-r-beginbmatrix-bbb-z-0-bbb-q-bbb-q-endbmatrix). In particular, the fact that \eqref{eq:1} holds for modules over a commutative ring seems to suggest that it might reasonably do so for bimodules over a non-commutative ring, at least when it is unital. On the other hand, unless I am mistaken, [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1593877/65389) simple computations give an example where \eqref{eq:1} fails to hold when $N$ isn't bilateral.

Comment: When $R$ is non commutative, $M\otimes_RN$ is just an abelian group. The isomorphism holds even if the direct sum is infinite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tensor product of a right module and a left module distributes over all colimits in both variables; you can show this by exhibiting suitable adjunctions. There is no need to assume that anything is a bimodule (which in any case is a structure, not a property). (For me all rings are unital.)

Comment: Could you link a proof of this statement?